# CSS drop down box Timed delay on menu shutting?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website that has an admin area where users are required to see notifications.

I have the whole notification idea set up with a CSS drop down menu but i cant seem to get the menu to stay open once the cursor is off the menu

I have uploaded the file into JSbin in hope somebody can help me

http://jsbin.com/ecegiy/1

It does not look like much on there as all the images and mysql connection files are not included but the css menu idea is included in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to let the menu stay open I'll suggest:

- Delete the css part of hover on sub-menu
  `#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  }`
- Give your menu an id
  `<ul id="childDisplay" class="sub-menu">`
- Add the javascript to upper element that it's always visible
  `<li onmouseover="menuVis.visible('childDisplay');" onmouseout="setTimeout('menuVis.unvisible(\'childDisplay\')',1000);">`
- Add the javascript class and method:

  ```
  function vis(){
      this.flag=0;
      this.flagUnv=0;

      this.visible=function(x){
        this.flag=this.flag+1;
        document.getElementById(x).style.display="block";

      }


      this.unvisible= function (x){
            this.flagUnv=this.flagUnv+1;
            if(this.flagUnv==this.flag)
                 document.getElementById(x).style.display="none";    
          }
  }
  menuVis=new vis();
  }
  ```

With this, the sub-menu will become invisible after 1000ms. If you want to keep it visibile "forever" just delete onmouseout section and the unvisible function.

Comment: Hi Simone cheers for your reply but im still having trouble with what you suggested :( Its not showing any menu now on hover. I wonder if that was the way i have implemented the JS what you think? If you could have another look at my code i would really appreciate it as this codes starting to drive me nuts haha jsbin.com/ecegiy/7 Cheers again Cory

Comment: Hi! No problem. I've tried on jsbin the code I've sent: this is the result jsbin.com/ecegiy/8/edit. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Simone Thank you yes this is exactly what i wanted it to do :) 
I also managed to notice where i had went wrong the 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Was missing for some reason i must have deleted it by mistake (oops ) but thank you so much for your help :) This code was starting to drive me nuts

Comment: No problem! :) glad it was helpful. By the way, if you want to accept the answer... ;) and ps: I've used counters (I've called them flag, really not a good choice) to avoid a problem when the mouse pass over the object more times and very fast. Just to explain.